# How to get value from the UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone

When i change the value in uIDatePicker at time no event is call.I want to gate change value from the UIDatePicker/

Answer (score 6):

Do you have something like this:

```
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And also:

```
    delegate = self;
```

Comment: Perfect except the 'delegate = self' bit can be ignored.